# Extracting value from an array of formArray elements gives error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form array in a form group defined as follows:

```
  agreementForm: FormGroup;
  agrArr: any[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.agreementForm = new FormGroup({
      serviceArr: new FormArray([])
    });
  }

  submitAgreement() {
    const data = this.agreementForm.value;
    this.agrArr.push(data);
  }

  submitForm() {
    console.log(this.agrArr);
    for(i=0;i<this.agrArr.length;i++) {
      for(j=0;j<this.agrArr[i].serviceArr.length;j++){
        console.log(this.agrArr[i].serviceArr[j]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Here, I am trying to have a form array within an array for master detail use. I am able to log the agrArr onto the console before the for loop, however when I get to the second for loop, I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'serviceArr')

And when I try to log in individual elements of agrArr onto the console I get undefined as the result. How can this be when I get the complete array at first? Where am I going wrong and how do I access individual elements of my two arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that to use find you first need to verify that the array is not undefined and also has a size greater than zero.

Try this:

```
submitForm() {
    console.log(this.agrArr);
    for(i=0;i<this.agrArr.length;i++) {
      if (this.agrArr[i].serviceArr && this.agrArr[i].serviceArr.length > 0) {
        for(j=0;j<this.agrArr[i].serviceArr.length;j++){
          console.log(this.agrArr[i].serviceArr[j]);
        }
      }
      
    }
}
```